# How to retrieve the column index in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In `ag-grid`, when I want to retrieve the row index I use:

```
params.node.id
```

However, I couldn't find a way to do the same for columns.
All that I found is retrieve the `columnId` which refers to the field variable in the column definition.
I.e: If this is the column definition:

```
 {
   headerName: "checkButton 2",
   field: "checkbuttonTwo",
   cellRenderer: "checkButtonComponent",
   width: 150
 }
```

This:

```
params.column.getId()
```

Would return:

```
 checkbuttonTwo
```

So my question is:
Is there any way to retrieve the column index? 
For example: For the second column I would have 2 and so on and so forth.
Thank you

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a helper function in TypeScript for getting the column index by col id.

```
function getColumnIndexByColId(api: ColumnApi, colId: string): number {
    return api.getAllColumns().findIndex(col => col.getColId() === colId);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I use the gridColumnApi and call its getAllGridColumns() method.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to get the column index, however you can use the `getAllColumns()` method on `Column API` to get all columns and then find the index of your column from that array.

More info on `Column API` [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-api/)

Comment: No, I actually found a trick to solve this. will post the answer later on

Comment: @AhmedGhrib could you share your solution with everyone?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **GridApi** to retrieve **columnDefs** like this:

```
api.getColumnDefs();
```

returned array **has the same order** as displayed data on the table.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the column `headerName` by running this function:

```
function CustomTooltip() {}

CustomTooltip.prototype.init = function(params) {
  var headerName = params.colDef.headerName;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

For each column, 
You can define a unique id this way:

```
{
          headerName: "Axa premises",
          field: "axPr",
          width: 150,
          id:0,
          cellRenderer:'iasaCheckboxRendererComponent'
            }
```

And you can access it in this manner:

```
this.params.column.colDef.id
```

Comment: You forced client to use number as id, This column could be reordered, what then?