# How to get the column index of the cell being processed in defaultColDef.cellClass in AG Grid

Tags: typescript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

In AG Grid community, in the cellClass function--when it resides in defaultColDef--I would like to know the column index of the cell being processed.  Is this possible to obtain?  I saw the following post, but even if I could get it to work (e.g. do I have access to the `colId` in cellClass? I haven't seen it), it would add a lot of processing to do all that finding for all of our 60+ columns: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64048964/442665

```
gridOptions: GridOptions = {
  defaultColDef: {
    cellClass: (params: CellClassParams) => {
      // HOW CAN I KNOW THE COLUMN INDEX?  I have 60+ columns in the grid
      const idx = params.colDef.cellClass.columnIndex; // I would *LIKE* to do this
      if (idx > 5){ // all cells after index = 5 are numeric
        return ['ag-cell-align-right'];
      }
      return '';
    }
  }, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
  getColumnIndexByColId(api: ColumnApi, colId: string): number {
        return api.getColumns().findIndex(col => col.getColId() === colId);
    }
```

and call it with:

```
this.getColumnIndexByColId(params.columnApi, params.column.getColId());
```